# Move file & Rename File in Google Drive

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I try to write script on Google Sheet to trigger below action.

Move a target file from root (my drive) to the destination folder then rename it in the destination folder.

Below items will be put on google sheet .  I want to create a formula function to trigger the script action once below items are provide on google sheet.
Target file name
Name ID for rename

Below script works perfectly (for move file action); i would like alter below script to accomplish above action.

```
function copyFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {

  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id); 
  var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id); 
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(id);

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    dest_folder.addFile(file);
    source_folder.removeFile(file);

  }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What's the point of the parameters since their already redefined within the function?  Also what sort of a trigger do you want to use? You might like to take a look at [setName() here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rename your file, you should have a look at File classe, on [File.setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String)) method.

Otherwise, you question is a bit unclear and need some explanations/examples of what you trying to do.